# How to fix " at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" " heroku error in go app

Tags: go, heroku

I'm setting up a go app and deploying with heroku. The app runs fine locally on localhost, 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0.

I had a port error which I solved by setting it so that if heroku didn't give me a port, I set it to 8080.

```golang
func main () {
    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == "" {
        port = "8080"
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/conservation/v1/", defaultHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/conservation/v1/country/" , countryHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/conservation/v1/species/", speciesHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/conservation/v1/diag/", diagHandler)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":" + port, nil))
}
```

It should work, everything I've found that says it should work doesn't help. When I for instance try to use the diag function I get

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/conservation/v1/diag" host=morning-temple-66987.herokuapp.com request_id=716af414-653a-4988-851e-f85d1a6ddb19 fwd="129.241.229.16" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

as a full error readout. Using /county or /species gives an near identical error message, just with a different path

I have narrowed it down to error code R10

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

The question is now, how do I fix error code R10?

Somehow, nuking the project and making a new one worked. I think it might have been an error in the Procfile, or in the go.mod file, something along those lines.

I deleted all the files and made a new app. Rewrote the Procfile and remade the go.mod. I kept the main.go file and it just worked

Comment: Can we get the content of the diagHandler function ?
It seems the error happens when you send a GET request to your app, on this endpoint specifically.

Comment: It happens to every function I try, diag is just the simplest to write. I edited the question to better explain the problem

Answer (score 0):

`os.Getenv` not necessarily returns "". Hence, use `os.LookupEnv` instead, ex.

Use

```golang
    port, exists := os.LookupEnv("PORT")
    if !exists {
        port = "8080"
    }
```

Instead of

```golang
    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == "" {
        port = "8080"
    }
```